# Using a Custom Post Type in your Website Manually

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Using the code below added to the functions.php file, I have manually created the custom post type, 'Products'.

How can I write a custom function to show the created products on all pages of my website? Which file would I add this to?

(I know there are plugins available to do this, I'm trying to learn the old-fashioned way first)

Thanks!

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'prowp_register_my_post_types');

function prowp_register_my_post_types()
{

    register_post_type(
        'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array('name' => 'Products'),
            'public' => true,
        )

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to make a custom query on the template file.
Let us assume your template file is running on index.php or single.php to show the content then querying like this should do the work after registering your custom post type

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Custom-Post', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="Custom-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```